# SelectList not loading selected or default value when loading view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a view which isn't displaying the selected/default value for an edit page. I've set the id, I've added a breakpoint and I can see that the select list has selected set to true for the correct member id, yet it's not reflected on my View, what am I missing?

If I set the selectedValue to a hard coded value I get the same result.

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult EditMember(Guid? id)
{
    var titleId = _context.Members.Where(x => x.RowId == id).Select(y => y.TitleId).FirstOrDefault();
    var editMember = new MemberViewModel
    {
        Titles = new SelectList(_context.Title, nameof(Title.TitleId), nameof(Title.TitleName), titleId).ToList(),
    };
    return View(editMember);
}
```

VM

```
public string TitleName { get; set; }
public int TitleId { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> Titles { get; set; }
```

View

```
<label asp-for="TitleId" class="col-2 col-form-label"></label>
<div class="col-10">
    <select asp-for="TitleId" class="form-control w-25" asp-items="Model.Titles"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="TitleId" class="text-danger small"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass your list in the viewmodel and set the selected property on the specific one e.g in your controller (Assuming you have an entity like Titles):

```
    public IActionResult EditMember(Guid? id)
    {
        var titleId = _context.Members.Where(x => x.RowId == id).Select(y => y.TitleId).FirstOrDefault();
        var editMember = new MemberViewModel
        {
            Titles =  _context.Titles.Select(g => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = g.ToString(),
                Text = g.ToString(),
                Selected = (g == titleId)
            }).ToList();
        };
        return View(editMember);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yap it's frustrated that selected item is working with old Html-helper-dropdown's but not with select

1. You can set selected item in select, only if you are not binding to a model

   `<select asp-items="Model.Titles" name="TitleId"></select>`

   Then you can bind "TitleId" on the server after submitting the form
2. If you leave your model binding you need to remove "asp-items" and populate your list manually.

```
<select asp-for="TitleId">
   <option selected disabled>Titles</option>    
   @foreach (var title in Model.Titles)
   {
     <option value="@title.Value" selected="@title.Selected">@title.Text</option>
   }
</select>
```

This way you have your item selected from the model

Comment: After hours of searching, the solution was option 2. Thanks!